# Git diff on moved directory

Tags: git, diff

In commit A, some time in the past, I had this directory structure:

```
foo
  bar
    a.txt
    b.txt
    c.txt
  baz
    d.txt
```

I now have:

```
foo
  ba
    r
      a.txt
      b.txt
      c.txt
    z
      d.txt
      e.txt
```

How do I do a directory diff of the `foo/ba/r` directory between now and commit `A`?

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
git diff -C A -- foo/ba/r/
```

Moves will be detected and followed.